# Understanding the Python netaddr library commands

Tags: python, ip, inetaddress

I am trying to understand how some code operates from the netaddr Python tutorials on https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html. In particular the following tutorial.

> Summarizing list of addresses and subnets
>
> Another useful operation is the ability to summarize groups of IP
>   subnets and addresses, merging them together where possible to create
>   the smallest possible list of CIDR subnets.
>
> You do this in netaddr using the cidr_merge() function.
>
> First we create a list of IP objects that contains a good mix of
>   individual addresses and subnets, along with some string based IP
>   address values for good measure. To make things more interesting some
>   IPv6 addresses are thrown in as well.
>
> ```
> >>> ip_list = [ip for ip in IPNetwork('fe80::/120')]
> >>> ip_list.append(IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/24'))
> >>> ip_list.extend([str(ip) for ip in IPNetwork('192.0.3.0/24')])
> >>> ip_list.append(IPNetwork('192.0.4.0/25'))
> >>> ip_list.append(IPNetwork('192.0.4.128/25'))
> >>> len(ip_list)
> 515
> >>> cidr_merge(ip_list)
> [IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/23'), IPNetwork('192.0.4.0/24'), IPNetwork('fe80::/120')]
> ```

I am a bit confused with the different options available. What is the difference between `ip_list.extend([str(ip) for ip in IPNetwork('192.0.3.0/24')])` and `ip_list.append(IPNetwork('192.0.4.0/25'))`.

If I don't want to start the list with an IPv6 (`fe80::/120`) and instead want to use an IPv4 (`192.0.4.0/24`) what would the syntax be. Would it be as simple as the following?

```
ip_list = IPNetwork('192.0.4.0/25')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is trying to demonstrate that the `cidr_merge()` function can merge a list of `netaddr.IPAddress` objects, IP address strings, and `netaddr.IPNetwork` objects into a minimal group of IP addresses and subnets. To do that a Python list containing various IP address related objects is created. That list is then passed to `cidr_merge()` to show that the ip address objects have been coalesced into a minimal collection of objects.

Initially it creates a Python list `ip_list` containing a number of individual `netaddr.IPAddress` objects. To this list it appends a `IPNetwork` subnet object. Note that this is a standard Python list operation - `list.append()` simply adds its argument to the end of the list, e.g:

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l.append(3)
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3]
```

`list.extend()` extends the given list with elements from another list (well, any iterable actually), e.g.

```
>>> l.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> print l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

See the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) for more details about these list operations.

So yes, it is as simple as:

```
>>> ip_list = [IPNetwork('192.0.4.0/25')]    # create a list containing IPNetwork object
>>> print ip_list
[IPNetwork('192.0.4.0/25')]
```

and appending/extending the list as required.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. Can you tell me if there is any diffrence between `ip_list.extend([str(ip) for ip in IPNetwork('192.0.3.0/24')])` and `ip_list.append(IPNetwork('192.0.3.0/24'))`?

Comment: @CMac:  Why don't you take a look at the lists after each operation is performed on an empty list? That will clearly show that there is a difference in `ip_list`. However, the result after `cidr_merge()` is run should be the same, i.e. both lists should give `[IPNetwork('192.0.3.0/24')]`.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the difference between Apend and Extend see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/1172412

You should be able to start the list like that.